# Tensorflow: How to load an object detection model and viewing the model's architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to load a object detection model and viewing the architecture because I need to know what my input and output layers are in order to convert the model format to a different format.

Right now, I am trying to do:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/my_ssd_mobnet_640x640_tuned/tfliteexport/saved_model')
model.summary()
```

And am getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-5f15418b3570> in <module>()
----> 1 model.summary()

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

My model is in .pb, but I do also have a .tflite version as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#savedmodel_format), you should load the model as keras model, like this:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("my/path/saved_model")
```

The `.pb` version should work.

Comment: Please, if this solved your problem, remember to accept the answer by toggling the check mark besides it. See [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)